# I've never thought vs I never thought

Tags: tense

1. What are you doing here! I'**ve never thought** I would see you here.
2. What are you doing here! I **never thought** I would see you here.

Are they both correct?

Answer (score 1):

The second is the correct usage. While the first sentence is incorrect (in the sense of how it is used along with this specific phrase, not that it’s incorrect grammatically or syntactically) another correct way to write it is “I would have never thought...” and, although this contraction is rarely used in formal writing, you may hear in informal speech “I’d’ve never thought I would see you here”.

Comment: Do we use the construction: "I'**ve never thought** I **would**..."?

Comment: "I would have never thought" is not at all natural, and feels wrong. Instead you would use "I would never have thought", or best: "I never would have thought". As for "I'd've never thought ..." that also sounds a bit wrong -- you'd be more likely to hear "I'd never have thought ..." which could be contracted to "I'd never've thought".