# I didn’t think Vs I have never thought

Tags: grammar

A scene in a novel I am reading.
Mr A just finished doing something surprising for Mrs B.
C is standing next to Mrs B, and asked: Was you surprised?
Mrs B answered like this:

The author wrote:

(1) I **didn't think** I could still be surprised at this point in my life.

How about this sentence?:

(2) I **have never thought** I could still be surprised at this point in my life.

Comment: I think you mean Mr. A just finished doing something surpris**ing**.

Comment: Thank you for your correction, I just edited my post. How about my question?

Comment: It's not a matter of *English* - #2 simply doesn't make much sense. The speaker is hardly likely to have thought at some time in the *past* that he wouldn't be thinking he could still be surprised at some point ***in his future***. Consequently the Past Perfect verb form doesn't work as given. But *I **would** never **have** thought...* works fine, as do *I never **thought...** and I **didn't** think...*

Comment: I agree with you that the speaker didn’t have any real thought of it , so that the version “I would have never” is good to use. I don’t understand why “I never thought” and “I didn’t think “also work.

Comment: See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/266329/ive-never-thought-vs-i-never-thought). _I never thought_ is an idiom meaning "I would never have thought that it was possible".

Comment: I had never thought  I would or could  be surprised again until I did it . Does it work ? I think so because doing this thing makes the man realised he had not thought about it before

Comment: If so what is the difference between “I had never thought “ vs “ I didn’t think”

Answer (score 0):

The first one means that she had didn't think that she must be feeling satisfied at this time. From this she is referring to the current happenings, but the other one refers to the entire lifetime.